# How do I keep track of activity by new users so I can encourage them?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

As [others have noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions), new users often need a little bit of encouragement. As a way of doing this, I'll sometimes look at questions and answers posted by new users and specifically try to help them. At the moment, the only way to do that is to look at the users page of a SE site and sort it by "newest", then open the users' profiles, and *then* open the questions.

When a site is growing, this can become onerous. Would it be practical to have the system create a list of questions and answers by users with less than [number] reputation? How would such a feature be implemented?

Comment: +1 Great idea, although I doubt it would get implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's already a *New posts by new users* link in the moderator tools that you get access to at 10 kRep on grown-up sites, or 2 kRep on fledgling sites.

See the [moderator tools privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) here on MSO, or its equivalent on other sites.

Comment: Any idea why the decision was made to allow only 10k+ users to access this feature on full sites?

Comment: @Neil: it's a moderator tool because those posts are often in need of editing or deletion: look at some of the other posts when you [search for "new posts by new users"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22New+posts+by+new+users%22).  I can't say why it was restricted to 10k users as opposed to, say, 3k users.

Answer (score 4):

> new users often need a little bit of encouragement.

The "New posts by new users" link mentioned in the other answer doesn't exist anymore. It looks like the First Posts review queue (and to a lesser extent, the Late Answers queue) have replaced it.

> Would it be practical to have the system create a list of questions and answers by users with less than [number] reputation?

This could be done with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but for a site the size of Stack Overflow this list would become very large rather quickly.