# Please lower rep threshold to get automatic notifications about new user activity

Tags: feature-request, support, new-users, 10k-tools

At [How do I keep track of activity by new users so I can encourage them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71172/287826), I read that there's a New Posts by New Users link in the moderator tools that you get access to at 10k reputation on grown-up sites, or 2k reputation on fledgling sites.

I have 8K rep at a small site (Spanish.SE) which was one of the batch of Beta sites that suddenly graduated a few months ago.

I don't think I have access to those notifications, but I would like to, since this would make it easier to welcome, guide, and respond to new participants.

I either need a feature change (lower the rep threshold) or instructions for how to use the existing feature (if I do have enough rep).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1439/discussion-on-question-by-aparente001-please-lower-rep-threshold-to-get-automati).

Answer (score 15):

That's an old question and that report doesn't exist anymore, not even for ♦ moderators. The [privilege page](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) doesn't mention it anymore, and neither does the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4576/295232). It might have been replaced by the First Posts review queue which (AFAICT) was created [somewhere in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75572/295232).

There is a related 10k report, 'New Answer to Old Questions', but it displays posts by veteran users as well. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340699/295232) is the first hit of that report on Meta Stack Exchange. You can find all these reports on the 'stats' tab of the Tools page, which is accessible on `/tools`; a link can be found on the main review page (`/review`); there's a Tools button on the top right.

Another option to get a list of new posts by new users, if you have the moderator tools privilege, you can also review other users' reviews at `/review/first-posts/history`. You don't need to pay attention to the reviews themselves, just click on the post titles:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that all questions and answers appearing from brand-new users will automatically, always show up in the review queue, whether they are of questionable quality or not, and that is the only way I can notice that there is a post out there needing a welcome note and a critical eye?

Comment: Yes, they will show up in the review queue (even if the user has the association bonus) and regardless of quality. Another option is to check the front page (for a site like Spanish.SE, that should be doable) or /questions, but there's no way to filter on reputation.