# Retaliatory downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette, new-users

So, after patiently trying to help a newb understand why his answer wasn't helping my question, and not wanting just to give him a down-vote without explaining why, I eventually gave up and just downvoted his answer. Then this happened:

[image]

And two seconds later:

[image]

And again:

[image]

The user in question had too little rep to actually down-vote, but it seems unlikely to be unrelated (I would guess a more established friend was involved).

It's kind of sad if this is the way the site is moving. Admit to down-voting someone and receive a "counter-attack". I tried to help this user, and I wouldn't have bothered down-voting if my question wasn't getting filled with poor answers, making it difficult for me to find useful ones.

Could StackOverflow do a better job of introducing the site to newbies, so they understand that a down-vote is just an opportunity to write a better answer and get the vote changed?

**Edit:**  To anyone who wants to suggest I brought this on myself by trying to help a new user, please give me a break. This is a community, and we all need to help new users understand that this isn't a normal forum. Lazily downvoting without explanation when it's not obvious to the poster what they've done wrong only creates more morons within our ranks. That's not helping anybody.

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)
[Downvoting of new user questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions)

Comment: Just a reminder: Mass-Downvoting will be caught by the Vote-Fraud-Script and will be reset every *wheneverythatscriptrunsialwaysforgetwhenthatis*.

Comment: btw. did you also down-vote my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php/768438#768438?

Comment: Self-inflicted.  Use a downvote to show that an answer isn't helpful.  Going on and on in the comments that a contributor is wrong or unhelpful is pointless.  Voting is anonymous, use it.

Comment: If you can figure out an anti-asshole filter, I think you'd make a bajillion dollars on the internets.

Comment: IMO, down-voting is for **wrong** answers. That answer is not wrong, it's just not *"gimmi-the-codez"* answer.

Comment: @vartec, Are you talking to me? If so, no.

Comment: @Hans, Trying to help someone improve their answer is preferable to mindless downvoting. In fact, just downvoting without explaining why is _discouraged_ here.

Comment: @yms, Are you serious? He didn't answer my question in the slightest. I am actually bewildered that you're under any impression that he did. The problem I was trying to solve was the placement of the modal Javascript, as clearly explained by the example in my question. His answer had _nothing_ to do with that. As for the accusation of wanting the code, if you understood the question, you'd know that the answer I accepted was actually unsuitable. The only reason I accepted it was because it gave me the idea of how to solve the problem. I didn't use a single line from that answer.

Comment: Sorry to rant :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The user in question had too little rep to actually down-vote, but it seems unlikely to be unrelated (I would guess a more established friend was involved).

The conspiracy is strong with this one.

Don't sweat downvotes.  Even retaliatory ones.  It's not worth your time or even the energy it requires to think about it.

I post awesome answers *all the time* and even **I** get downvoted occasionally.

Comment: nice try, making this CW to attract downvotes...

Comment: @Shog9 You better not downvote me. [I'm watching you, Wazowski. Always watching. *Always.*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtWBlDC2-ss)

Comment: and @Shog9 shows up to make sure nobody is out-conspiracy-ing him with the first comment, of course

Comment: Thanks, Adam. You're right. I should let this drop. Can't stop the morons, I guess.

Comment: "I post awesome answers all the time " +1 for awesomeness