# Should we have a down-vote “safe zone” for new users with less than 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, down-votes, new-users

I think it would be good for people with less than 50 reputation to have a down-voting “safe zone” because they are new and don’t know the system yet. Down-votes destroy their interest to answer questions or even ask them.

Should we have this functionality?

Comment: What do you mean with "safe zone"?

Comment: I guess you're suggesting that a person with under 50 rep shouldn't lose any rep for a downvote or that it simply isn't possible to downvote their post?

Comment: Then people wouldn't learn what they must do, and soon people with 51-100 reputation would need a safe zone too.

Comment: @PeterJ yes i mean that

Comment: i just say my opinion why i get downvote :-O

Comment: Because on meta downvotes means dis-agreement. [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @rene: That is just on feature requests.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, I know. curently it has that tag but it didn't this morning and most regulars forget that rule easy...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sadly the help center doesn't do a particularly good job of summarizing voting patterns on meta.  Questions putting forth a proposal will typically results in votes for or against that proposal, regardless of what tags the question uses.  That said, this question *is* a feature request.  Mis-tagging the feature request by removing the tag doesn't make it not a feature request.  The question is requesting a feature, and thus the tag is appropriate.

Comment: Downvoted because I disagree with this feature - new members need to learn the rules and quality standards required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I disagree. New users are helped a lot to know how to act inside the community. When they don't follow the rules, they should be treated like everyone else.

Some things are in place to help:

- The help tour;
- The First Post queue;
- A very nice search functionality which prevents asking a duplicate question.

If new users don't respond to the help they get, and keep posting questions that show no effort, no research, nothing, they deserve every downvote they get.