# New user "bad question" tweak/push?

Tags: feature-request

Prompted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089826/java-programming-for-beginners), with input from [this meta Q&As](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions).

If the mission is [re-]education and an overall increase in quality, how about sending them to a mandatory "how to ask questions the smart way" **from which they cannot escape until they read it, re-vamp their question,** and (possibly) have it vetted by some tender eyes/fingers?

There's a badge for going through the FAQ, how about a badge for surviving a doggie-pile, going to question rehab, making good on their question, and having the cajones to show their face still?

Comment: *'from which they cannot escape...'* - and every page visted on SO will auto-redirect them to that page until they fix their question? Love it!

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stackoverflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgator)

Comment: When would this mandatory thing pop up? Their first question, any low-quality-filter triggering question, any question when the user is close to the questionban threshold, or what?

Comment: @Toomai In my head, when a doggie-pile was detected, they'd basically see it before they could do essentially anything, along with the (forced) "opportunity" to edit. I don't know about the questionban threshold, but my thing is more of a "let's force help upon hapless new user that just got body-slammed."

Comment: Oh so you were thinking more along "when their question gets a -x score" while I was thinking like "just before they try to post a question".

Comment: @Toomai Correct; this is more of a "forced mentoring before you can do anything else" thing, based on a new(-ish?) user not doing well. There's too much downvoting w/o a lot of feedback--this would at least force some info onto them, with a goal to rehab the user and/or question. If it had the potential to be a good question, either re-ask the same question w/o the downvotes, or ask an entirely new question.

Answer (score 5):

> how about sending them to a mandatory "how to ask questions the smart way"

This is already in-place. There's a EULA shown to every new user having <=10 rep

[image: Question EULA]

Comment: Embed deep in the middle "if you click the checkbox below you will be permabanned from StackOverflow"

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking for, though.

Comment: It covers the first part of what I want, but not the rest. It's the difference between telling someone "don't abuse drugs" and forcing them to go to supervised rehab.