# Why are there some type of questions that are open and highly upvoted, while others of that same type are closed? Can someone explain?

Tags: discussion, questions, broken-windows

I am posting this question just to get a better understanding of the questions that can be asked on Stack Overflow.

I find that [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages) can several answers based on users opinion and cause a discussion.

Why is this a good question when several other requests for books and tutorials are not acceptable?

Comment: I'm surprised it hasn't gotten a historical lock yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252985/resource-on-computing-time-complexity-of-algorithms - Another similar link, there are many more ...

Comment: It's fairly simple: the site guidelines have changed over time. Questions that were permitted 4 years ago are not necessarily welcome today.

Answer (score 5):

If you explore the archives, you'll notice a lot of these types of questions.  Just browsing the top 5 all-time rep users' top questions/answers turned up these, which would all be considered bad questions on today's Stack Overflow:

- [What's the strangest corner case you've seen in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-sharp-or-net/194671#194671) (Marc Gravell)
- [What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion) (Jon Skeet)
- [Why is WinRT unmanaged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457371/why-is-winrt-unmanaged/7457964#7457964) (Hans Passant)
- [Examples of GoF design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195) (BalusC)

You'll notice that these questions are mostly more than a few years old; and have been closed as off topic or not constructive.

Even though those types of open-ended questions generate some really interesting content, you can imagine why the powers that be outlawed them, as they distract attention from the core purpose of a Q-and-A site.

Answer (score 4):

The questions you're linking to are extremely old. Question constraints were more lax back then, in part because there was a lot less traffic. The first question used to have a disclaimer on it that said something along the lines of "This is not a good example of a Stackoverflow question; it's being preserved because blah blah blah."