# Why is the difference between these two questions? Why is one closed, and one open?

Tags: discussion, broken-windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there some type of questions that are open and highly upvoted, while others of that same type are closed? Can someone explain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145350/why-are-there-some-type-of-questions-that-are-open-and-highly-upvoted-while-oth)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120329/kendo-ui-vs-jquery-ui

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484648/kendo-ui-vs-wijmo-ui

The first one has never been closed; the second one was.

Why? What is the difference?

Comment: Time. The first was asked much earlier, when that was "ok"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the early days of Stack Overflow, there have always been a set of standards and guidelines derived from the vision that Jeff and Joel had for making a great Q&A platform to make the Internet a better place.  As Stack Overflow has grown in size and scope, it's become clear that these standards have to be enforced.

Thus, some questions from the past -- and even some today -- sometimes slip through the cracks. As more and more people are educated with what to do with these types of questions, we'll hopefully see less and less of them slip through the cracks.

With that said, it looks like your mention of them has already given the older question 4 close votes. It just needs one more to be closed.

In summary, we don't use open questions as evidence that similar questions can be asked here, precisely because of the community education and the fact that some questions just slip under the radar. Hope this helps!

Comment: To be fair though, the first question is from only a year ago. It's more likely that it just went unnoticed for all that time. Maybe it got 3-4 close votes, but with the high churn in jQuery, it never garnered enough for the 5.

Comment: You may be right @NicolBolas, but I'm surprised it never got flagged by a < 3000k user. That would have exposed it to quite a few 10Kers and even a moderator.

Comment: Older question is closed now