# border question closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there some type of questions that are open and highly upvoted, while others of that same type are closed? Can someone explain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145350/why-are-there-some-type-of-questions-that-are-open-and-highly-upvoted-while-oth)

Take for instance:

[Create session if none exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432536/tmux-create-session-if-none-exists)

this was not closed.

However, this was closed:

[Kernel hacking methodology - how to find out where to hack the linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305162/kernel-hacking-methodology-how-to-find-out-where-to-hack-the-linux-kernel)

Where's the logic?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It has now been closed, and logic has been maintained. Thank you for helping to make this site better by pointing out questions that should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

The first question was asked in 2010 when the rules for what was on topic and what was off topic were somewhat different and less strictly enforced.

The second question is more of a [Super User](http://superuser.com) question. I can only assume that it didn't get migrated because it didn't get 4 migrate votes.

Both questions are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The second question is far more open-ended than the first.

The question about tmux is reasonably bounded. The questioner provided command line examples with their results and clearly stated his goal (have tmux connect to an existing session if there is one).

Contrast these excerpts from the second question (emphasis in original):

> My question is *what methodology should I follow systematically to
>   find out what devices are responsible for those leds* (in general, not
>   necessarily specific to my hardware).

And:

> when I say methodology, I really mean the methodology, step by step,
>   with reasons for each step

IMHO this calls for answers both generic and extremely detailed. It might be the reason why the question was closed.