# Is there anything like an "offense" count?

Tags: support, post-ban

Today I found this ["banned to ask question" thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183437/banned-for-ask-question).

It is marked as duplicate of ["what can I do..." thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), where most questions are already answered.

But there is one thing that is missing:

How can a user know about an impending question / answer ban?

Is there an offense count? (perhaps I just do not have one in my SO account).
Is there a hidden "three strikes" mechanism to ban users?

Comment: I believe the exact algorithm is complicated (for example i believe good questions can "make up for" bad questions) and deliberately secret

Comment: So the user does not know that he is on the wrong path until it is too late?

Comment: Not exactly, no. There are visible indicators that they're doing something wrong. Heavy downvoting, questions being closed, posts being deleted are all indicators that they need to rethink how they're using the site. They're not exactly official warnings, but they are the community saying "You're doing something that we consider inappropriate."

Comment: More or less, I never said I agreed with it (that said its usually lots of downvotes/closed/deleted questions, so fairly obvious), the one thing that suprises people over and over is that self deleted questions are included

Comment: I have to see if I can find them, but there are several [meta-tag:feature-request]'s to provide feedback to users approaching a question/answer ban.

Comment: @MareInfinitus A responsible user should never even be close to that 'path' to begin with. The system is _very_ forgiving for bad questions and answers as it is.

Comment: Related: [Question Ban Meter - Feature Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168263/question-ban-meter-feature-request)

Comment: People know from downvotes and closed questions when they're writing bad questions.  Some people just don't seem to care until they're banned.  Other people do care, so they improve their questions and never get banned.

Comment: Some people do care AND get their questions closed.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179124/147247

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple: One is writing bad questions.

That seems like a no-brainer, but obviously many users do not realize that downvoted questions (or for the most part not upvoted ones) are bad questions. Especially if they get deleted or are deleted by their owner. All of this information is already available all over the site.

An indicator would allow users to balance on the edge of the ban and always getting away with asking bad questions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in which way "You're writing bad questions" is an answer to "How can a user know about an impending ban"?

Comment: @MareInfinitus "An indicator would allow users to balance on the edge of the ban and always getting away with asking bad questions." means there is _no_ indicator, and he is _against_ having one.

Comment: I think the issue is that a new user might not even know about the ban in the first place. And I would think that it would be harder for a user to balance on the edge in the first place and most likely a user wo could do that would just write good questions anyway.

Comment: What if a person was to know all the laws of a country and thereby avoid breaking the law and going to jail. What a terrible world that would be(!)

Comment: "You're writing bad questions" sound very offensive to me, did I understand that right?

Comment: `"An indicator would allow users to balance on the edge of the ban "` - how do you figure?

Comment: This suggests people "want" to write bad questions

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Huh? Naahhh, that wasn't directed at you.

Comment: @Mike: Imagine you're speeding, and everytime a radar-station or police car you get a warning.

Comment: There are gadgets for that. In my home country this is legal, as it makes you drive at the correct speed.

Comment: Ah the old "one" vs "you" problem, call me a old man but I think the language was better when people said "One is writing bad questions". I'm 26

Comment: @RichardTingle: No, I don't think users *want* to write bad questions. Bad users have shown a *very, very, very* high creativity when it came to circumventing bans or limitations.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Uh, I like that!

Comment: In england on the first driving offence you get a warning (insurance companys may not have this information, it affects nothing), then points (which are a harsher form of warning) then and only then do you get a driving bad. Works pretty well here

Comment: @RichardTingle: In Austria you got to pay (or your license is redacted, depends on speed)...maybe I should stop using analogies. :/

Comment: Analogies are good as long as they support what <one> wants to tell ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle Writing high quality questions is hard.  It requires a lot of time and effort.  Asking a question without doing your research, making an effort yourself, and taking the time to formulate it well is a quick and easy alternative to spending your own time, and thus many people ask questions that they're capable of solving on their own or turning into high quality questions.  So yes, many people do want to ask bad questions.  The question ban is there to prevent people from doing so continually.

Comment: There never was a doubt about the need to ban users. But I think any user should know about it before it happens. A simple notification about "SO rules" and the fact that a user could be banned should be enough.