# Is Stackoverflow headed in the right direction?

Tags: discussion

I've tried asking a question, and began getting bad feedback with barely any clear comments on what's inappropriate about it. Now I no longer have access to asking new questions. I've read http://goo.gl/C1Kwu and have tried editing my questions to be more formal and clear. However nothing seems to help.

[How to assign to a variable an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025870/how-to-assign-to-a-variable-an-alias)

So honestly...where is this website headed?

I am not here to spam or be provocative, I'm here to be productive and try and contribute to the enterprise of knowledge these forums provide, without offending the epistemology of it. Do these policies truly set path for productivity? Tt seems rather counter-productive

Comment: Negative feedback != bad feedback.

Comment: You only have one (visible) question with a score of less than 0. It's impossible to get question banned from this alone. Have you deleted a number of questions?

Comment: this is why I proposed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183496/can-the-post-ban-message-show-links-to-deleted-questions-or-answers

Comment: @ben: (in all seriousness, I checked and found quite a number of those)

Comment: This seems like one of the rare edge cases where the post ban *may* have been applied unfairly. However, it isn't very productive to turn that unpleasant experience into a discussion about the *entire site's* direction. I understand full well that it feels bad to be banned, but overall, the post ban works *extremely* well. It is one of the most important protectors of our sanity here on SO.

Comment: I don't believe to have deleted more than one or two questions before.
I agree with you Pekka, but What else is there for me to do?

I enjoyed using this website to collobrate with experts. But this is a real bite in the back, and no moderator nor user has been suggesting what's wrong and how it can be fixed. 

It's like entering a grave

Comment: You are no longer question banned on [SO]. You have 8 deleted questions, so be careful, as the automated ban might kick back in if you delete any more.

Comment: All "internet" "mod" based discussion sites/apps/sources inevitably deteriorate to trigger happiness. Live with it or move on to the next "big thing".

Comment: @echad: I checked - your deleted questions are not visible to you from your profile, but I found about 8 of them which you deleted yourself, presumably from downvotes and/or comments, or that you somehow found the answer yourself and deemed the question not worth keeping around.

Comment: @echad: I don't think you were 'unbanned' by the moderators; it is more likely that you were *close* to no longer being banned and enough things changed that the ban no longer applies *right now*. But that means that you are still close to the threshold.

Comment: echad - what @MartijnPieters says is right. We don't have the power to unban anyone, but it looks like you were on the edge and things turned your way.

Comment: Got it, I still think it wouldn't hurt to consider this question. I'd recommend warning people who are on the edge of being banned. It could help them by hinting not to take things lightly

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you get many chances to write better questions. It's not like at your first *offense* (writing a *bad* question.. well, a question that doesn't fit our standards) you could get banned.

If you are question banned it is because you didn't take the time to learn from the previous negative feedback you had. Every users, especially new ones, will get some downvoted posts along the way. Look at my questions history and you will see that the more I advance on this website the more I learn to formulate good posts and, therefore, get more positive feedback. (Except on Meta but here downvotes aren't interpreted the same way).

> So honestly...where is this website headed?

As far as I'm concerned, and I'm sure a lot of users share my point of view, the site is heading right the way it should be heading right now. A few things could change here and there but these are technicalities and that's what meta is for.

Answer (score 5):

**Where StackOverflow is heading**

According to the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

As long as your questions are suitable for inclusion in the "library of detailed answers" you will fit in here. If you have a history of asking question that are not good additions to that library, the system will recognize the pattern and take appropriate action.

**What you can do**

[Read more about what to do when you are banned.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: FAQs or About pages only show the site's owner's intent.  That's about as far from reality as you can get.

Comment: @Andomar The site owner's intent dictates the guidelines for the activity that happens on the site. This is a dynamic community, sure, but the rules and procedures (such as the automatic question ban) are manifestations of the "official" intent.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins It's like telling someone to read a textbook then apply deduction reasoning until one has figured out which reason it's for. Then to find out if it's even possible to be unbanned. 

I'm not sure how this banning process is initiated (by moderator or robot) but s/he or it ought to return an explanation like an **`fprintf(stderr, "deleted too many questions")'**

This will be time efficient on his half, and the website's progress half

Answer (score 2):

It's headed exactly where its users are headed.  If you do your best to make it a useful site, then you're helping the site succeed.  If you turn all your answers into "Debbie Downer", people may not return.  Just like in life, just do your best to make everyone's day productive.