# List items inside of quotes have their bullet points outside the box

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

I just noticed a little visual inconsistency on a question on Meta ([Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179106/make-users-pass-a-review-assessment-as-final-stage-before-question-ban/179124#179124)). The bullet points of list items, if inside a blockquote, are outside the containing box.

#### Screenshot:

[image]

In my opinion, they should be indented, just like the ones in normal text.

Comment: Which browser? [That is not what I see here](http://i.imgur.com/tuPdqGO.png) on Chrome.

Comment: I don't see it on Chrome or Firefox (Linux). The real problem is those bullets aren't actually part of that blockquote (they would need to be indented further), but they still have the background for you

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't even thought about that. I'm using an old Mac OS X 10.4 machine with Safari 4.1.3. Is this the whole issue? Then I'm sorry for asking. :x

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Well, the *real* problem is that those bullets *are* part of the blockquote, even though it's not possible for them to be. But it seems newer browsers are better about correcting the faulty tags.