# Is there another reason for banning?

Tags: support, post-ban

I'm banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow. Refering to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past.

But I don't understand what a low quality question represents for you. Because I only asked two questions (you can view my profile) and they aren't that bad, they were both helpful.

And an even bigger problem is that you are expecting me to do positive contributions while I'm banned. How is this even possible?
Is the ban related to something other than questions/answers?
I'm trying to make sure I understood this well.

Comment: What about the four that are deleted?

Comment: From the page you link: *"but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or **deleted posts**."*

Comment: From other accounts?

Comment: What deleted questions.How can I see them

Comment: Go to your list of questions in your profile. There should be a recently deleted link at the bottom. If that doesn't show anything, perhaps a moderator can link you to them.

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Please link them to me.

Comment: Your deleted question are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719442/the-return-in-php-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622322/website-ideas-for-new-features and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591382/are-c-and-c-sharp-the-same. The last two were also closed before being deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF these are 3 questions where is the forth one?

Comment: @user689 - I can't see a 4th. Oded, in a comment on his answer, said - "the one to disassociate one of the worst offenders."

Comment: I have disassociated one of the deleted questions so it doesn't count against you anymore, to help you get out of the qban. That's why there are only 3.

Comment: @Oded Can't you disassociate the other two they seem uneditable and stupid at this point.

Comment: Of course I _can_. But I won't. You need to be careful from now on and I will not give you a free pass.

Comment: @Oded the problem is that I can't undelete the last two questions.

Comment: And wait what's wrong with the down votes is this a low quality question?I find it very useful

Comment: P.S. you must be floating around the border - you're not currently banned on SO. Use it wisely.

Comment: @Flexo no I am.

Comment: Jeez. I disassociate yet another question, you get unbanned, then ask [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741138/how-to-set-a-ruby-app-on-a-website) (+10k link) and there you go, back into the ban.

Comment: @Oded that question was asked before the ban and I couldn't edit it.

Comment: No. The ban was lifted 2 days ago. You then asked that question and got back into the ban. As for editing it - your own (not-currently-deleted) posts can always be edited by you.

Comment: @Oded I'm sure: there were two questions before the ban " print "#{x}" and print x" and the one you are talking about. I edited the deleted one based on your demands to increase the quality of my posts and it got downvoted thats all.

Comment: @Oded how many points should I earn to get unbanned. I have 23 right now(I'm trying as hard as I can.)

Comment: I am really not inclined to help you out any more. When I did, you proceeded to ask something that was off-topic, making me regret ever helping out.

Comment: @Oded I **did not** ask any question after the ban I'm pretty sure. The problem was that a guy downvoted an old question I had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what a low quality question represents for you

That's subjective. But in aggregate, if the people who saw the question acted on it by downvoting more than upvoting, that tends to tell you it is low quality.

Lack of proper grammar, punctuation, syntax and over/under-use of formatting are all indicators of low quality. Questions that do not share their research / code. Answers that are only a single link.

---

We don't disclose the exact algorithm so it won't get "gamed" - that is, we don't want it publicly available so people can get away with *just* enough bad.

Things that contribute to the ban - getting more downvotes than upvotes, deleted posts. There are other signals, but I won't be disclosing them or exact numbers.

In your specific case - there are 4 deleted questions that are still contributing to the ban. As it stands, you only have 1 post with a positive score and one with 0, all the others are downvoted to some extent.

If you can, undelete the "best" ones and **improve** all of them by editing them, adding information and making them better in general.

Comment: How can I reach these deleted questions? I don't see them

Comment: @user689 - If they have not been deleted recently, you can't (in your question page there is a link at the bottom for recently deleted posts). But you can flag one of your _open_ questions and ask a moderator to undelete posts for you.

Comment: @Oded I can say that none of those deleted questions should be undeleted. But it looks like a CM disassociated one of them.

Comment: @animuson - I looked at the questions and agree with you. I was the one to disassociate one of the worst offenders.

Comment: Isn't that a bit unfair? Everyone doesn't learn at the same pace. I cannot see the deleted questions, but looks like he has posted 4 bad questions, not 400. Is the user even warned about the upcoming ban *before* he goes over the mark?

Comment: @Happy - getting downvotes on your questions doesn't count as warning? There is an about page and help center for people to read - those are clear about the community expectations.

Comment: @Oded How many times have *you* gone to a *new* forum/discussion board/Q&A site and read the help before posting anything? Also, do you seriously expect every new user to go through 30-odd pages on the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before they even post a question? *You* have been around this site for a long time so this might seem so trivial to you. Food for thought: How many seconds does it take you to find the statement in the help page that says receiving too many downvotes can get you banned? You don't have to tell me, just try counting it, you might get the idea.

Comment: Also how much effort does it take to send a notification to the user that says, "Your account has been making too many low quality posts, and might receive a ban. You are encouraged to improve the quality of your posts to prevent this from happening. Read "X page" to learn how you could improve the quality of your posts." or something to that effect?

Comment: I have never come across any person who signs up for a new site and thinks, "Let me first find out what can get me banned from the site before I post anything." "Receiving too many downvotes can get you banned from StackOverflow" is not some universal truth taught in primary school, so no, it is not enough of a warning. You are assuming that a newbie somehow magically knows that accounts can get banned from StackOverflow, and will then also realize that downvotes could contribute to getting banned. Long story short, things don't work that way in the real world.

Comment: @Happy - I expect people to **look around** before posting. In the days of usenet, people were expected to "lurk" before posting. The idea that you should learn how to behave in a new place before starting participation is not something I think is overly onerous.

Comment: @Happy your concern about warning is not new and has been discussed here before. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow and the questions linked from it - that should save us rehashing the conversation here in the comments

Comment: @Happy Once a post is closed or significantly downvoted, it's not too much to expect users to take a step back, figure out what went wrong, and improve from there on out. And telling people that "they might be banned" is an excellent way to ensure that they will try to play with the system, remaining on the edge. It's not much of a guarantee they will actually improve.

Comment: Adding to my last statement - if people actually took some time to look at what happens to different questions on Stack Overflow **before** posting, they would see that certain questions get downvoted and closed and others do not. You seem to think that they shouldn't be expected to spend even a little time familiarizing themselves with a **new** Q/A site/forum/whatever before posting - I disagree, @Happy (perhaps Charla could, with her bit of clairvoyance)

Comment: @Happy, *"How many times have you gone to a new forum/discussion board/Q&A site and read the help before posting anything?"* I cannot speak for Oded, but I've *always* read the guidelines and looked around before posting. On SO, you even get [the How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before you can continue. And I don't think the guidelines here are that odd at all: even if I had not read them, I'd not have posted crap that would have gotten me a posting ban.

Comment: "In the days of usenet," - hah - we're through the looking glass into the pages of Animal Farm...  Didn't Joel (and Jeff?) love to endlessly bash Usenet when they set up Stack Overflow?  What's the best number of legs at the moment...?

Answer (score 6):

There are positive contributions galore - most of which produce rep for you

- answer questions.
- suggest edits
- accept answers to the questions you've asked
- comment or edit your questions and answers in response to comments by others as you learn how the site works
- ask questions. You can't make new ones any more but you can edit your existing ones, including the deleted ones, in the hope that they become a positive contribution. (After editing, flag the question and ask for it to be undeleted. Make sure you understand what makes a question good before you do this.)

Many people who get a question ban overcome it by contributing positively to the site.

To see your deleted questions, view your profile, and in the Questions section click view more or the Questions heading itself. Then scroll down to the bottom and look for a link "deleted recent questions".

Comment: It says there is no deleted questions.

Comment: no **recent** deleted questions. As others have told you, flag any of your other questions and ask for links to your deleted questions

Comment: @user689 the questions were deleted in March and April of this year (2013) some time ago now.

Comment: Of these, only 'suggest edits' seems to be of any practical value to him. To answer questions, you pretty much have to be an expert *and* answer first (or at most second), otherwise you are accused of copying from other answers and/or low quality posts, which will further worsen his case.

Comment: @Happy I disagree entirely. Many questions are answered by non experts. Many second answers are good. Accusations are rare and even if they happened, and were accompanied by downvotes, 1 upvote and 1 downvote means a net rep gain. I don't know the ban formula but I expect it would help to have some upvotes for some answers.

Comment: Let's have a look at a few of these questions which a beginner could answer after an expert had already answered them, and didn't get burned for it.