# Unclear why warning about low-quality-question is displayed

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, post-ban

Before you flag this question as a duplicate of [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow), please consider that I'm not discussing if such a warning is useful (I fully agree that it's useful), but instead I have problems following the advice given in the warning because I seem to have ran into a special case (deleted questions which I can't see anymore). This topic might need attention from an SE developer.

---

**Question**:

When I go to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask then I get the warning

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
> you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

along with some helpful links for resolving this issue.

However, when I go to my profile, I see only one question, and it's currently upvoted with 2. I think that this can't be the reason for the warning, so I don't understand why the warning is there.

Maybe in the past I had bad style questions on android.stackexchange.com which were deleted, but now I barely remember and I can't find them and I can't improve them. So the warning is there for a reason which I can't reconstruct. So ultimately, the warning is almost useless for me, except that it vaguely tells me to do better.

I think that this warning shouldn't be there, or that it should give me more information what I have been doing wrong. Can I switch it off somehow or do something else about it?

Comment: I see three questions. Two of which are deleted - neither of which has any upvotes. The message is correct - deleted posts contribute to question bans.

Comment: The warning is there so you take note. Which you have. Job done?

Comment: @Oded, that's a good start. Can you tell me how I can see my deleted questions? When I go to my profile > questions > deleted recent questions, it says that there are none.

Comment: They are rather old (not recent enough to be shown) and don't appear salvageable - no real point in trying to fix them. Going forward, I suggest you ensure your questions are high quality and on-topic (read the Android site help center documentation to find out).

Comment: @Oded, I think there is a misunderstanding here. I do not fear being blocked, because I'm quite sure I can create high quality questions (the sample of 3 questions is just too small to be representative; look on SO if you need proof). My problem is that there is a warning and I can't follow the reason behind it. I have no way of seeing exactly what I did wrong in the past. It only says "you did something wrong", but if I want to improve, this statement doesn't help me. And I anyways try to make good quality posts to the extend of most of my skills, so I can't even simply improve my posts.

Comment: I agree it's not a dupe but don't want to be the one to start hammer wars. Prefer that either @Martijn will cast the vote, or five others.

Comment: Go to your profile, hit the questions link, scroll to the very bottom, click on 'Deleted Recent Questions'.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, they aren't in this list, because they're too old. They're not recent anymore.

Comment: @Lance Oded mentioned this in his second comment. :)

Comment: +1 for asking constructively, recognizing the value of what's there, and earnestly seeking an answer. I think I agree you'll have little trouble moving forward.

Comment: Marked as dupe of newer question as it got an official answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, no it's not a duplicate. Please read carefully and comment here if you can't find the difference.

Comment: Well, it's tricky but please try to follow my logic. You ask "Why I see this message?" and as Oded answered in a comment it's because you have deleted questions hence you're close to the edge. The other question asked the next question: "What should I do?" which got an official answer. So while not direct duplicate, I find the logic close enough. If you still feel strongly that's it's wrong let me know and I'll reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I understand your point. It turns out that there is no solution currently for my question, because that warning works as designed. In particular, it also tells me "edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity" in a case where this is impossible to do. I think this should not happen. How to ask for a change of this behaviour? Whom?

Comment: @Daniel edit the question here. change the [meta-tag:support] tag to [meta-tag:feature-request] tag instead and revise the whole question to just ask "Please change the wording of the message", explaining your reasoning and suggested change. When you're done let me know and I'll reopen. Since this question still has no answers I think it's fine. :)