# What should I do when I see a "question ban warning"?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

When I [ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) question, It says following:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Here is screen-shot:
[image: screen]

So, What should I do? (How long to wait?)

Comment: Wait long enough to digest the message, then follow its advice. Read the links, and improve on past questions.

Comment: Getting the same thing here on Meta SE. with similar amount of downvotes.

Comment: @mhlester Ok now how to improve this question!

Comment: Apparently, there is nothing you can do. It appears to be a case of "strike one and you're out!" I have just made (18 months later) the same mistake (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251677/why-am-i-being-told-past-questions-have-not-been-well-received-and-youre-in-d), and after only 24 hours or so, I already have twice as many downvotes as you! We are in the same sinking ship and no-one will save us ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The message is there to be read, understood, its links followed, read and understood as well.

And then, we hope you follow the advice and start asking better questions - at this point, this is up to you. If you ask better questions, you will not get blocked. If you don't ask better questions... well, you did get a warning, right?

Comment: Just curious: are the links referring to http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (and their site-specific equivalents)?

Comment: @Arjan I figure yes, they are. (The user seems more active on AU, which has questions quality bans enabled.)

Comment: I wonder if the OP is talking about Meta SE. I'm getting a question ban warning here too as well, and I my posts weren't that downvoted. (He even links to the SE ask page).

Comment: @justcool393 The warnings are enabled on all sites, regardless of whether the ban is or not. I don't know if the ban is enabled on meta..

Comment: @Oded I want to delete my question!?

Comment: @andya - Why? It is a useful question to have on the site. Other people who encounter the message and are confused can now find it and get a response. Which is the goal of our sites - to have questions and answer that are useful for many people.

Comment: @Oded -- If it is such a useful question -- and i, too, believe it is -- then why does it also (presumably other OP questions also have down-votes) get down-voted so much?  All these down-votes are a terrible blow to one's self-esteem. That is, they are an insult and, in this case especially, hypocritical. It's like the Salem Witch trials all over again. Or, mixing metaphors, "Have you ever been guilty of asking, or thinking about asking, a bad question? Anything you say, or don't say, will used against you!"

Comment: @martinf - voting should be done against a **post** not a person. The message comes up after a **pattern** of bad posts. If someone can't separate voting on the quality of the post that's a shame - but people are not voting against a person here. Useful doesn't mean it it **good** - that's very much what the downvotes would signify.

Comment: @Oded: Sorry, i don't understand the latter part of this: "Useful doesn't mean it it good - that's very much what the downvotes would signify." The question is getting down-votes because it is useful?

Comment: @MartinF - no. It gets downvoted because it is bad, off-topic, badly phrased, shows no research or one of many other reasons. A question being useful doesn't mean it can't also suffer from other issues that would make it a target for downvotes.