# Can you improve "past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban, warning

I was about to ask a question, here on Meta SE, when I was slapped with the above warning. I went into a state of shock and "before I knew it" I had posted a completely different and obviously self-defeating question.

I thought -- and have only just realized, incorrectly so -- that I was being black-listed *system-wide*. (I just now went to various "main" sites to which I belong and, *even on a site at which one of my few questions was ill-received*, I am not given any such warning/slap.)

Thus, I ask:

1. Can you make the warning a little less confrontational, so it has the desired effect yet in a kinder, gentler manner?
2. Can you make the warning point to, or somehow list, the questions which were poorly judged -- as Shog has done below?
3. Can you make it clear that the warning only applies to *this* (or whichever) site and in no way is a reflection on contributions made on other sites?

I sincerely believe this "feature" needs some tempering.

Comment: Note: the question is now *considerably* different from its original incarnation!

Answer (score 13):

This is your question history here on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

That's one positively-received question, followed by two duplicates - the last downvoted and deleted.

The trend is not... positive. Hence the warning - the system's trying to tell you that you might want to try a different tactic.

Which... I guess you sorta did, but, I don't think this is gonna help.

Maybe have a nice cup of tea before you post your next question?

Comment: Thanks, Shog. I've now slept on it *and* had my cup of tea, literally! I strongly suggest that telling someone they have a poor question history, based on only two out of three well-meaning attempts, is the wrong way to go about things and will lead to self-fulfilling prophesies --that the likes of Lightness thrive on-- and a lot of ill-feeling. I believe that over a few years i've made a contribution to the SE family and went into a state of shock and despair when faced with what still appears to be unfair criticism. It could have killed me, literally. (Depression can be fatal.)

Comment: We resisted adding those warnings for a long, long time @martinf - for exactly this reason. Eventually, we had to accept that *not* giving folks some sort of warning was doing more harm than good - still, it remains a trade-off. But with changes now in the pipeline, we may be able to drop some of them or adjust the thresholds at which they appear.

Comment: Why was the 3rd deleted? I thought there was a policy *not* to delete duplicates (to increase a topic's reach). Was there even a warning given to me? How do i improve a deleted question?