# Feature request not well received, risk of being blocked?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban, warning

Related questions:

[Can you improve "past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251677/can-you-improve-past-questions-have-not-been-well-received-and-youre-in-dange)

[What should I do when I see a "question ban warning"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234042/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-question-ban-warning)

However I would like to address **a specific case: feature requests**. I [recently did one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252190/marking-a-question-posted-with-an-answer-with-an-information-box) that was not well received. Feature requests questions [might be downvoted when one disagrees that the feature should be implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252209/225842). Now, if you get a ban, the [guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) says:

> All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so
>   put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting
>   your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as
>   possible about your problem and what you have already tried. Reading
>   your question out loud to yourself can help you understand what it
>   sounds like to others.

However, the automatic algorithm does not know about the quality of a post, it knows about votes, and for feature requests the votes can be very low even if the quality is ok. That puts in danger low rating users (but maybe experienced from other Stack websites) who want to propose an idea, and contribute to the website.

Is this is a relevant problem? How could be this situation prevented/mitigated?

Note: I know one "bad" question alone is not sufficient to get the warning. But since I got another question closed, I got a warning and for example now I am at risk even by posting this very question. Where I think I did my homework, but God knows who I can find out there in this dark night... :)

**Edit:**
*(This was the status of this question when justcool393 updated his answer)*

Now I read about [Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually/)
However, why is the warning still so scarying?

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from
>   accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past

(Note: I am still readying details, but I urged to edit here to save this question from being closed)

*(Then the question got closed so I moved to a new, more specific question)*

Comment: Since the question has been marked as duplicate, I removed my recent edit and placed in this new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252261/why-do-we-threaten-so-quickly-with-an-automatic-ban

Comment: You need this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: @random Let me try to understand: Are you trying to be kind? In that case I appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think on this site, the warning triggers at the same rate as on normal sites, but the actual ban triggers at a much different threshold and you apparently have to basically be trying to get hit by the actual question ban.

See also:

[Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually/)

**Edit:**

Since you seemed to have added another question, I'll go ahead and answer it here. The warning is supposed to make you stop, and say "hey, I want to make sure this is a good question" before submitting, and this is the reason to keep the site quality high.

While the warning may be triggered at a lower threshold than it should, it is a good reminder. I've gotten it too on MSE before, but you can pretty much get out of the warning if you balance it with other types of questions, or a feature request that would be more popular (there isn't really a way to gauge the latter without just asking it).

Comment: Gosh! This question is duplicated, I am doomed!

Comment: @Antonio: Don't get too worried. The threshold is unknown (to prevent abuse, I guess), but you should be okay.