# On Stack Overflow, if my *answered* question has been downvoted into negative territory, will deleting it put my account at risk?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, down-votes

Thanks for looking.  I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622323/are-there-any-established-c-sharp-image-interpretation-algorithms-or-patterns) on SO last night, and it didn't go over so well with some folks.

This morning, I see there is one answer (for which I am thankful) but that I have also been downvoted to a balance of -1 so I attempted to delete the question to prevent further reputation damage.  However, when I attempt to delete, I get this dialog:

[image]

I don't think I have deleted any answered questions before, so this hasn't been a problem until now.

## My Question

I don't know the algorithm SE uses for these cases of course, so I am wondering if I delete the question--considering that it is in negative territory--will that be a "mark" against my account.  Obviously, I like being here and don't want to put my account at risk.

## Bonus question

What I don't get is that the question has (presumably) been downvoted by high-rep SO members who have commented that the question is vague, not helpful to the community, and so on.  Additionally, it has been put on hold.

So, if the question isn't a good one and not valuable to other developers, why would I get a dialog stating that closing it could deprive future readers of knowledge and therefore it can be a strike against me?

The question is either useful and in-line with SE rules or it isn't--at least that's what I get told quite often in the comments.

Comment: I obviously don't know the algorithm, but it's possible that a self-deleted question at -1 penalizes less than an undeleted question at -10. So deleting a question to avoid further downvotes isn't necessarily a bad idea. Of course there's easy no way to find out.

Comment: @Mysticial--Thanks, but as Servy is pointing out below, there is apparently no way to know what the actual  penalty of deleting is.

Comment: With regard to "if the question isn't a good one and not valuable to other developers, why would I get a dialog...", the code that displays the dialog isn't in a position to evaluate the quality or worth of the individual question. It's generic text about deleting a question that has an answer; it only knows it's a question with an answer that you're trying to delete. ("Answer count > 0? Show dialog confirming deletion" is simple logic.) You get the same confirmation question if you try to delete a question that has positive votes and has an answer; it's generic text.

Comment: Thanks, but I would have to say that "Answer count > 0 && Votes > -1) ? Show dialog confirming deletion" is also simple logic ;).  It's the principle behind the logic that is in question at this point.  Thanks again.

Comment: I covered why the votes weren't considered (in the last sentence of my previous comment). Again: you get the same confirmation question if you try to delete a question that has **positive votes** and has an answer. Vote count doesn't matter to that dialog - **deleting the question that has an answer does**.

Answer (score 11):

> if I delete the question--considering that it is in negative territory--will that be a "mark" against my account?

Yes, it will.  That's *exactly* what the dialog is telling you.  It's not lying to you.

To your second question, it'll still be counting against you a fair bit even if you *don't* delete it.  The point is that deleting it doesn't clean up your record and remove all negative consequences of asking bad questions.  If you keep asking bad questions you'll end up banned, whether you delete the questions or not.

The message is there because many people seemed to be under the false impression that as long as they kept deleting their bad questions they'd be able to keep asking them.

Comment: The problem is--at least from my perspective--it is getting harder and harder to know if your question is good or bad.  Sadly, your answer speaks to the broader problem here with folks making their own interpretation of the rules or what constitutes a bad question.  Case in point, you say that it is "exactly" what the dialog is telling me when, in fact, the dialog states ". . .CAN result in your account being blocked. . ." not ". . .WILL result in your account being blocked. . ." and therefore my question here remains unanswered.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt It does count against you, there is no question about that.  Whether having one more thing count against you will be the straw that breaks the camel's back and causes you to be banned, is not nearly as certain.

Comment: @Servy--Thanks for your response.  Is there, then, not a place where we can view the "strikes" against our account so that we know when we are in danger of being banned?  Seems like it would only be fair for a user to know where they stand in that regard.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt No, there is no way of seeing how close you are to being banned.  This is intentional.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt If you are really close to the ban, you should start seeing a [message when you ask another question warning you about getting banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/160551).  I don't know how far in advance the warning triggers though.

Comment: @Troyen--Thanks, that is very helpful.  I don't think I would be considered a "trouble maker" and I doubt if I am close to any ban, but still it would be nice to know if I am close.  Thanks again.