# Do negative points hurt you in any way?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, asking-questions

If you get a lot of negative points will yo just not be able to ask questions anymore or does it just mean you rank lower on [the questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: You can clearly see your earlier post still listed there.

Comment: It depends what site you accumulate the downvotes on. Some sites invoke question bans for persistent low-quality posts (of which downvotes are some, but not the only, measure).

Comment: If you did get banned would that be temporary or permanent? And if it were temporary how long would it be?

Comment: The only other real impact other than possible question/answer ban, is taking away your privileges, which are granted based on the current reputation.

Comment: Sorry to hear that dude.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears that the user is not really seeking a real answer but rather trolling us to waste our time.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow

Comment: I think it is hysterical that this question got down-voted 5 times! hahahah

Answer (score 3):

Downvotes are a reflection of how the community perceives your post. Folks reading your work are encouraged to vote according to how well-written, well-researched and generally *useful* they see it.

Votes are *primarily* a way for readers to provide feedback to other readers. If your post is widely perceived as less useful, it will be made less visible. But votes do have a secondary function, as a form of feedback: if you realize that readers are finding something you wrote to be useful, you've learned something about what sorts of writing are appreciated; by the same token, if your post is being downvoted, that's a good indication that you might wish to review it yourself with an eye toward finding areas in which to improve.

If you develop a *reputation* for writing posts that are seen as useless, the system may try to discourage you from writing more of them, either by imposing a waiting period or blocking you outright. These are rare, and the vast majority of people writing here do not ever need to worry about them - however, if you find that over time you're getting more downvotes than upvotes, you should probably be concerned *anyway;* if nothing else, you're wasting other folks' time.

We've written several guides to writing better questions and answers. You can find them in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).